# 404 Not Found Next.js error on React-Query fetch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-query

Here is my situation. I am trying to set up a Next.js project with an Express.js back-end. I did set up the back-end as a regular one not as a custom server according to Next.js documentation. So I am not sure if I am already making a mistake by setting up the back-end as a regular one. I am trying to fetch data from a back-end endpoint `http://localhost:3500/api/v1/list` using axios and it works well. But when I am trying to implement React-Query on the first load I am getting the right data from the back-end but when it is trying to re-fetch for some reason it is hitting the wrong end-point `http://localhost:3600/api/v1/list` and getting the 404 Not Found error. It looks like it is switching the port from `3500` to `3600` which is a front-end port. Here you will find the [link](https://github.com/forza11879/next-e-commerce/blob/main/pages/sell.js) to the repository and here is the code. Let me know if I am doing something wrong,

**page/sell.js**

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { useQuery } from 'react-query';

export default function SellPage({ response }) {
  const { data, isLoading, error } = useQuery('sells', getPosts, {
    initialData: response,
  });

  console.log('data useQuery: ', data);

  if (isLoading) return 'Loading...';
  if (error) return error.message;
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Hello SellPage!!{data.message}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const response = await getPosts();
  console.log('response', response);
  if (!response) {
    return {
      notFound: true,
    };
  }

  return {
    props: { response }, // will be passed to the page component as props
  };
}

async function getPosts() {
  console.log('HOST: ', process.env.HOST);
  const { data } = await axios.request({
    baseURL: process.env.HOST,
    url: '/api/v1/list',
    method: 'get',
  });
  return data;
}
```

**_app.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider } from 'react-query';
import { ReactQueryDevtools } from 'react-query/devtools';

const queryClient = new QueryClient();

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  const queryClientRef = React.useRef();
  if (!queryClientRef.current) {
    queryClientRef.current = new QueryClient();
  }
  return (
    <>
      <QueryClientProvider client={queryClientRef.current}>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
        <ReactQueryDevtools initialIsOpen={false} />
      </QueryClientProvider>
    </>
  );
}

export default MyApp;
```

Comment: `HOST:  http://localhost:3500`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see a `next.config.js` in your repo,  so I guess the env variables are not bundled in the js and in the end you url looks like `localhost:` or `localhost:undefined` which the browser default to the port your client is served.

Try add `next.config.js`

```js
module.exports = {
  env: {
    HOST: process.env.HOST,
  },
}
```

SEE: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/environment-variables

Another way is to use public runtime variables

```js
module.exports = {
  publicRuntimeConfig: {
    // Will be available on both server and client
    port: 3500,
  },
};

// Then
import getConfig from 'next/config';

// Only holds serverRuntimeConfig and publicRuntimeConfig
const { publicRuntimeConfig } = getConfig();
console.log(publicRuntimeConfig.port);
```

SEE: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/runtime-configuration

But note that runtime config would impact optimization and you might get larger bundle in the end so you might want to try build time variables first.

Comment: I am using build-time environment variables `https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables` as per docs advice.

Comment: @John John Does it log 3600 in the browser? Can you show the next.config.js?

Comment: i just pushed it to the repository you can find the link in the question

Comment: yes the front-end runs on 3600. the back-end on 3500

Comment: publicRuntimeConfig made the difference

Comment: in fact, I'm not getter any error using your repo with request to `/list` instead (to cope with `json-server`) :thinking:.
maybe a restart would also help you.
might need more inspection on network to really understand.

Comment: but anyway, you could start with `publicRuntimeConfig`

Comment: `publicRuntimeConfig` fixed the issue. I am not really sure why .env file is not enough. Maybe I am not getting the whole picture. Thank you for looking into it!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228982/discussion-between-seanplwong-and-john-john).

Answer (score 0):

if you get 404
i think that you reached out the server but no API's name matched
so try to test the API first on postman or alike
however if  `console.log('HOST: ', process.env.HOST);`
prints `http://localhost:3600`  then do the following
in your `.env` file try to rename `PORT` TO `SERVER_PORT` or whatever

```
HOSTNAME=localhost
SERVER_PORT=3500
HOST=http://$HOSTNAME:$SERVER_PORT
```

i'm not sure but maybe ur frontend serve bash hold `PORT` env val as `3600`